# udev inside lxc container

Tags: xorg, udev, devices, lxc, xinput

I am running a privileged Debian LXC Container on Proxmox, and then running Docker inside that. I am attempting to run an Xserver in a Docker container with Sunshine to stream to a Moonlight client. I am using the project named 'Games on Whales' for this. Sunshine dynamically creates some input devices during it's start up and during client connection.

Here are some of the relevant lines from the lxc conf:

```
features: nesting=1
lxc.mount.entry: /run/udev var/udev none bind,optional,create=dir
lxc.mount.entry: /dev/uinput dev/uinput none bind,optional,create=file
lxc.mount.entry: /dev/input dev/input none bind,optional,create=dir
lxc.cgroup2.devices.allow: c 10:* rwm
lxc.cgroup2.devices.allow: c 13:* rwm
```

I symlink'ed `/var/udev` to `/run/udev` in the container, and then mount that through to my Docker containers. Xorg is able to pick up on all my input devices, but does not pick up on the devices which Sunshine creates. I can see these devices work and see input coming through when I use `evtest` on them. The problem is that `udev` events across the LXC boundary (I think?), and so Xorg isn't adding the new devices.

Here is the udevadm monitor output on my Proxmox host:

```
❯ udevadm monitor -s input
monitor will print the received events for:
UDEV - the event which udev sends out after rule processing
KERNEL - the kernel uevent

KERNEL[124160.238916] remove   /devices/virtual/input/input160/mouse7 (input)
UDEV  [124160.258704] remove   /devices/virtual/input/input160/mouse7 (input)
KERNEL[124160.264249] remove   /devices/virtual/input/input160/event23 (input)
UDEV  [124160.265212] remove   /devices/virtual/input/input160/event23 (input)
KERNEL[124160.284184] remove   /devices/virtual/input/input160 (input)
UDEV  [124160.284846] remove   /devices/virtual/input/input160 (input)
KERNEL[124160.340229] remove   /devices/virtual/input/input161/event24 (input)
UDEV  [124160.340751] remove   /devices/virtual/input/input161/event24 (input)
KERNEL[124160.356212] remove   /devices/virtual/input/input161 (input)
KERNEL[124160.356378] remove   /devices/virtual/input/input159/mouse6 (input)
UDEV  [124160.356729] remove   /devices/virtual/input/input161 (input)
UDEV  [124160.358682] remove   /devices/virtual/input/input159/mouse6 (input)
KERNEL[124160.376267] remove   /devices/virtual/input/input159/event22 (input)
UDEV  [124160.376817] remove   /devices/virtual/input/input159/event22 (input)
KERNEL[124160.400155] remove   /devices/virtual/input/input159 (input)
UDEV  [124160.400604] remove   /devices/virtual/input/input159 (input)
KERNEL[124163.533210] add      /devices/virtual/input/input162 (input)
KERNEL[124163.533254] add      /devices/virtual/input/input162/mouse6 (input)
KERNEL[124163.533320] add      /devices/virtual/input/input162/event22 (input)
KERNEL[124163.533592] add      /devices/virtual/input/input163 (input)
KERNEL[124163.533623] add      /devices/virtual/input/input163/mouse7 (input)
KERNEL[124163.533675] add      /devices/virtual/input/input163/event23 (input)
KERNEL[124163.534019] add      /devices/virtual/input/input164 (input)
KERNEL[124163.534048] add      /devices/virtual/input/input164/event24 (input)
UDEV  [124163.558279] add      /devices/virtual/input/input162 (input)
UDEV  [124163.559783] add      /devices/virtual/input/input162/mouse6 (input)
UDEV  [124163.560873] add      /devices/virtual/input/input164 (input)
UDEV  [124163.560960] add      /devices/virtual/input/input163 (input)
UDEV  [124163.562461] add      /devices/virtual/input/input163/mouse7 (input)
UDEV  [124163.628764] add      /devices/virtual/input/input163/event23 (input)
UDEV  [124163.636735] add      /devices/virtual/input/input164/event24 (input)
UDEV  [124163.636769] add      /devices/virtual/input/input162/event22 (input)
```

And here it is in the LXC container.

```
❯ udevadm monitor -s input
monitor will print the received events for:
UDEV - the event which udev sends out after rule processing
KERNEL - the kernel uevent

KERNEL[124160.238840] remove   /devices/virtual/input/input160/mouse7 (input)
KERNEL[124160.264292] remove   /devices/virtual/input/input160/event23 (input)
KERNEL[124160.284242] remove   /devices/virtual/input/input160 (input)
KERNEL[124160.340233] remove   /devices/virtual/input/input161/event24 (input)
KERNEL[124160.356212] remove   /devices/virtual/input/input161 (input)
KERNEL[124160.356397] remove   /devices/virtual/input/input159/mouse6 (input)
KERNEL[124160.376315] remove   /devices/virtual/input/input159/event22 (input)
KERNEL[124160.400172] remove   /devices/virtual/input/input159 (input)
KERNEL[124163.533247] add      /devices/virtual/input/input162 (input)
KERNEL[124163.533283] add      /devices/virtual/input/input162/mouse6 (input)
KERNEL[124163.533371] add      /devices/virtual/input/input162/event22 (input)
KERNEL[124163.533590] add      /devices/virtual/input/input163 (input)
KERNEL[124163.533623] add      /devices/virtual/input/input163/mouse7 (input)
KERNEL[124163.533682] add      /devices/virtual/input/input163/event23 (input)
KERNEL[124163.534049] add      /devices/virtual/input/input164 (input)
KERNEL[124163.534106] add      /devices/virtual/input/input164/event24 (input)
```

Is there something I can do to make `udev` work inside the container? Should I pursue some other route to get Xorg to pick up on Sunshine's dynamic input devices?